# How to animate widgets automatically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Future` which returns a `List` and using `FutureBuilder` and inside it a `ListView.builder` I show data that I got from `Future`.

But the problem is, whenever `Future` returns data my list of widgets just pops directly into the screen. I want to give it a animation (fade or curve) which I am not supposed to trigger manually, instead I want that when I got the data from `Future` my list to pop to screen not direcly but with some latency/fade/curve or any other animation.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a opacity animation, [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation) you can see an example.
Then you can set

```
bool _visible = true;   //Put this inside your initState


            AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                child:ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: count,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                                       return Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(this.list[position].name),
                        subtitle: Text(this.list[position].type),
                        trailing: GestureDetector(
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.grey,),
                          onTap: () {
                              _delete(context, list[position]);
                          },
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          debugPrint("ListTile Tapped");
                          navigateToDetail(this.list[position]);
                        },

                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
            ),
```

Comment: how this animation will be triggered?

Comment: This might help [link](https://medium.com/flutteropen/animation-01-how-to-use-the-animation-in-the-flutter-e3ef7043f940)